# RedisTimeSeries to create time chunks of data

Tags: redis, redistimeseries

I am new to redistimeseries. Can we use it to create... let's say 5 seconds chunks of incoming data stream with timestamp ?

I tried using range queries to get the time chunks which works fine but wanted to know if we can create a rule which keeps on bucketing 5 seconds data.

Comment: By "bucketing", do you mean compaction (downsampling)? Hence storing a single aggregation (e.g., sum/max/min/avg) per bucket?